# How is Spektr-R doing these days?

Tags: russia, high-earth-orbit, radio-astronomy, spektr-r

Under the question [What are Spectr-R's major contributions to radio astronomy that could not have been done from Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33564/12102) there is a [new comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33564/what-are-spectr-rs-major-contributions-to-radio-astronomy-that-could-not-have-b?noredirect=1#comment112023_33564) that points (again) to the BBC News article [Spektr-R: Russia's only space telescope 'not responding'](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-46849347).

Is there any newer information? Has reliable communication been re-established? Three months later now, how is Spektr-R doing?

Comment: https://www.roscosmos.ru/26397/ seems to say that the mission was official declared as over

Comment: @samcarter Thanks! That's good to know; would you consider posting that as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On May 30 there had been a meeting concerning the status of Spektr-R. Afterwards Roscosmos published a statement at https://www.roscosmos.ru/26397/

Here a machine translated version using www.DeepL.com (if any Russian speaker is around and would like to provide a real translation, I'll be happy delete this answer):

> Spectrum R: Mission accomplished, data processing ongoing
>
> On May 30, 2019, a meeting of the State Commission for the Review of the Flight Tests of the Spectrum-R spacecraft was held. The State Commission, having heard the reports of representatives of the rocket and space industry and scientific community, decided to complete the project "Spectr-R".
>
> At the beginning of January Spectr-R spacecraft stopped contacting the Flight Control Center. Attempts of NGO specialists named after S.A. Lavochkin to ensure communication with the spacecraft as part of the Chief Designer's program were unsuccessful.
>
> The Spektr-R spacecraft (Radioastron) worked for the scientific community 2.5 times longer than planned and exceeded all its main functions as a source of valuable scientific data on our universe. During its work, the Earth's scientific community has received a significant amount of data on the structure of the universe, the processing of which is unfinished and actively continued by scientists of the planet.
>
> At the end of June 2019, the Spektr-RG will be launched, which will create a map of the universe, where all large clusters of galaxies will be marked. With its help, scientists around the world will be able to answer the question - how the evolution of galaxies occurred. Work is also continuing on other scientific instruments of this series, Spectrum-UV and Spectrum-M.

The summary seems to be that attempts to re-establish communication have failed and the mission is officially declared finished.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the answer and effort, and also thank you Spektr-R for all the data! by the way, this still needs an answer: [What are Spectr-R's major contributions to radio astronomy that could not have been done from Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33564/12102)

Comment: [1](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28814/7982), [2](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/30018/7982), [3](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32850/12102) (the other end of the spectrum)

Comment: @uhoh You have unanswered questions ready for about every possible user to come by, don't you? :)